# Mystery WIFI connection interruption

Tags: wifi, connection

The issue is that Windows users disconnected from WIFI network every 2~10 minutes, Mac users are less frequent but still get kicked off 1 or 2 times a day. We don't have such issue with any wired computers.

The coverage is good enough even for corners, and average number of users on each WiFi access point is around 10~30.

The DHCP least time is 21600s(5 hours)

By "kicked off" I mean the L2 connection failed. We use several different brand of WIFI APs in the network, 4 Unifi from Ubiquiti Networks, 1 Cisco, 1 Netgear, all have same issue...

Comment: How close are these APs to each other? And are they configured to use non-overlapping channels?

Comment: Yes, they're on different channels. Each AP connect to directly to the main switch of the floor.

Comment: What about networks other than yours? What models are the AP's? Almost every time I have had trouble with getting kicked off of a wireless networks it is because of interference (mostly from other wireless networks), or because a consumer router is being overloaded by too many clients.